# Querying, Ordering, and Selecting from a Row by String Value Across Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-macros

I have a Google Sheet file called `Shipments` that contains shipments delivered to different warehouses, with fields `Delivery Date - Company Name - Shipment Type`, and I have a sheet called `Companies` which has a columns `Company Name - Membership Status - Rating`. All of these values are pulled **automatically** from a different GSheet, they are not entered manually, so row orders change.

I want to pull the last shipment delivered for a company in the Shipments sheet into a "Last Delivery Date" field in the Companies sheet, so the Companies sheet has the following columns:

`Company Name - Membership Status - Rating - Last Delivery`

I think I have to do a query or a named range that is something along the lines of `SELECT ONE Delivery Date WHERE B (column for company name in Shipments) === A (column for company name in Companies) ORDER BY (last delivery date column) DESCENDING`

Not sure how to accomplish this in GSheets, am exploring queries now. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you add a sample spreadsheet showing what is the outcome you expect and the functions you have tried so far to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in `Companies!D1`:

```
={
  "Last Delivery";
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    IFNA(VLOOKUP(
           Companies!A2:A,
           SORT({Shipments!B2:B, Shipments!A2:A}, 2, FALSE),
           2,
           0
    ))
  )
}
```

Assuming `Company Name` is in `Companies!A:A` and in `Shipments!B:B`, Delivery Date is in `Shipments!A:A`.

[image]

---

Maybe there is a more elegant solution that uses `QUERY`. Could not come up with one on the spot.